# How do I reverse a string in java by creating a new temporary string?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

What's the error in the following code? I am not able to identify it shows the index 0 out of bounds exception.

```
public class stringBuilders{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Shubham");
            StringBuilder str2= new StringBuilder();

            int j=0;

            for(int i = str.length()-1; i>=0 ; i--)
            {
                str2.setCharAt(j++,str.charAt(i));
            }

            System.out.print(str2);

        }

}
```

Comment: check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-in-java/) it will help you,also this code  `new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()`

Comment: Change `str2.setCharAt(j++,str.charAt(i));` to `str2.append(str.charAt(i));`.  

Delete the variable `j`.

Comment: The method `setCharAt` only works to replace characters at already existing positions. It is not meant to be used to add new characters to your StringBuilder, that is what `append` is for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there an error in your code? If you are seeing any error message or any unexpected result, please specify and paste into your question. It’s much easier to help you with an error when we know what it is or how it manifests.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already iterating from end to start you can just append the characters to the fresh and empty string builder. `setChar()` is only intended to replace existing characters.

```
public class StringBuilders {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Shubham";
        StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            str2.append(str.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println(str2.toString());
    }
}
```

gives

```
$ java StringBuilders.java
mahbuhS
```

Answer (score -2):

You haven't declared a value to the `str2` string.

The for loop is trying to find a character at index `j=0` in `str2` to set value `i` of `str2`, which it cannot find.

Hence the error.

For this to work, you need declare a value of str2 to a length >= str1. i.e., if `str1 = "0123456"`, **str2** should be at least `0123456` or more.

Instead of using `StringBuilder` to set the `char`, you can use `String` to just append to it.

```
        String str1 = new String("Shubham");
        String str2 = new String();
        
        int iter = str1.length() -1;
        
        for(int i=iter; i>=0; i--) {
            str2 += str1.charAt(i);
        }
        
        System.out.println(str2)
```

Comment: do not perform concatenation in string, it's quite costly, as it will create new object for each operation
for the above same code just use stringBuilder instead of String

Comment: There is no reason to use `new String("Shubham")` or `new String()`. Just use the literals `"Shubham"` and `""`.